# React front end for R Shiny backend

Tags: r, reactjs, shiny

I want to create interactive dashboard using React as a frontend and R shiny as backend. I want to know how to pass data from shiny to react and react to shiny.

There are no any articles or documentation related to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.react/index.html helps.

Comment: Shiny is not really meant to be used as a backend. If you want to build an API backend, look into plumber https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plumber/index.html

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/stla/shinyChakraUI can help.